# Docker Optimizing a Container Build

Tags: docker

I have a docker file with the following content

```
 FROM python3:7
 pip3 install func-timeout
 RUN (commands)
```

The problem I am having is that the `docker build` command is taking too long, and the main
`pip3 install func-timeout` is taking the most time during the build. Is there a way to pre-cache this step to decrease build-time? The use case for this is that I will be frequently modifying `(commands)` and building new containers from the modified image from within the same machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using `FROM python:3.7-alpine` so the size will go down much and it will be more secure then you can add only the needed packages. As long as you don't have the mentioned problem [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=description).

For caching, that depends where are you going to build and run that but normally caching mechanism is available in different CI/CD tools so  maybe you just need to enable and locally docker will cache layers.

Comment: Is there a way to explicitly tell docker to cache the step `pip3 install func_timeout` when running `docker build`?

Comment: By default locally, it will be cached if the layer of this command is available and nothing was changed. If you have a very advanced use case then read docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) how to change caching behavior.